# Is there any way to log MLflow model coming from tensorflow.keras using custom model wrapper?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, mlflow

I am trying to log a Tensorflow.keras model using mlflow. In my workflow I need to define a custom *.predict()* . So based on [this](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/mlflow/mlflow-end-to-end-example.html) I have done these steps:

First I trained the tf.keras model as following:

```py
 _input = (
            tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
            .repeat()
            .batch(1)
            .batch(WINDOW_SIZE)
            .batch(MINIBATCH_SIZE)
            .map(lambda x: (x, x))
        )

        tf_model = Seq2Seq(WINDOW_SIZE=WINDOW_SIZE).get_model()
        tf_model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
        tf_model.fit(_input, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=3)
```

Once the model is trained, I have lodaded it using mlflow.pyfunc:

```py
class NNModelWrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(
        self, model, input_name, target_variance, ffill_limit, sample_rate, window_size
    ):
        self.model = model
        self.INPUT_NAME = input_name
        self.TRANSFORMED_INPUT_NAME = f"zscore_{self.INPUT_NAME}"
        self.TARGET_VARIANCE = target_variance
        self.FFILL_LIMIT = ffill_limit
        self.SAMPLE_RATE = sample_rate
        self.WINDOW_SIZE = window_size

    def predict(self, context, input_df):

        df = input_df #apply preprocessing functions...
        
        input_data = df[self.INPUT_NAME].values.flatten()
        transformed_input_data = df[self.TRANSFORMED_INPUT_NAME].values.reshape(
            -1, self.WINDOW_SIZE, 1
        )
        result = self.model.predict(transformed_input_data)

        result = result.flatten()
        result = result * np.sqrt(self.TARGET_VARIANCE)
        result = np.where(result < 0, 0, result)
        result = np.where(result > input_data, input_data, result)

        return pd.DataFrame({"time": df.index, "inference": result}).set_index("time")

py_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(mlflow.get_artifact_uri() + "/model")
        wrapped_model = NNModelWrapper(
            model=py_model,
            input_name="input_P",
            target_variance=10,
            ffill_limit=180,
            sample_rate="1T",
            window_size=WINDOW_SIZE,
        )
```

With this model wrapper I am able to get something when calling *.predict()* method. Everything fine here.

```py
df = get_fake_timeseries(start="2021-01-01", end="2021-01-02")
result = wrapped_model.predict(context=None, input_df=df)
```

But the problem comes when I try to log the model using mlflow library again. This line of code gives the following output.

```py
signature = infer_signature(df, result)
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
      "wrapped_model", python_model=wrapped_model, signature=signature
      )
```

```
...

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 496, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Any ideas on what could be doing wrong?

Comment: same here, could you find a fix?

Comment: Not at all, instead of using mlflow python model for tensorflow I decided to use pure tensorflow model and apply my custom my custom preprocessing and postprocessing code within a tensorflow signature. This makes the model fully portable but you can only use tensorflow operations when coding the preprocessing/postprocesing steps. 
Here you have an useful post about tensorflow signatures if you want to give it a try https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/03/a-tour-of-savedmodel-signatures.html